# Using linq group by to get from a list of objects with a DateTime property to a list with an interval StartDate, EndDate

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a booking entity which stores data by day, based on this I would like to be able to create another list which stores the data by intervals(StartDate, EndDate) if the dates in the first list are consecutive, and the grouping should be based on the pair { VenueId, TimePeriodId}. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
public class BookedRoom
{       
    public int VenueId { get; set;}        
    public int TimePeriodId { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }        
}

 public class EventSetup
 {
    public int VenueId { get; set; }        
    public int TimePeriodId { get; set; }        
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }       
 }

List<BookedRoom> bookedRooms = new List<BookedRoom>(){
            new BookedRoom { VenueId = 1, TimePeriodId = 1, Day = new DateTime(2013, 9, 1)},
            new BookedRoom { VenueId = 1, TimePeriodId = 1, Day = new DateTime(2013, 9, 2)},
            new BookedRoom { VenueId = 2, TimePeriodId = 2, Day = new DateTime(2013, 9, 3)},
            new BookedRoom { VenueId = 1, TimePeriodId = 1, Day = new DateTime(2013, 9, 4)}
        };


        // Some Linq to process bookedRooms and obtain a list which I can use to do the following:

        List<EventSetup> setups = new List<EventSetup>()
        {
            new EventSetup{ VenueId =1, TimePeriodId = 1, StartDate=new DateTime(2013, 9, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 2)},
            new EventSetup{ VenueId =2, TimePeriodId = 2, StartDate=new DateTime(2013, 9, 3), EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 3)},
            new EventSetup{ VenueId =1, TimePeriodId = 1, StartDate=new DateTime(2013, 9, 4), EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 4)}
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` in combination with `SelectMany` and `Aggregate` for this:

```
var setups =
    bookedRooms.GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.TimePeriodId, x.VenueId))
               .SelectMany(x => x.Aggregate(
                                    new List<EventSetup>(), AccumulateRooms))
               .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
               .ToList();

List<EventSetup> AccumulateRooms(List<EventSetup> existingSetups,
                                 BookedRoom currentRoom)
{
    var setup = existingSetups.LastOrDefault();
    if(setup == null || setup.EndDate.AddDays(1) != currentRoom.Day.Date)
    {
        setup = new EventSetup
        {
            VenueId = currentRoom.VenueId,
            TimePeriodId = currentRoom.TimePeriodId,
            StartDate = currentRoom.Day.Date,
        };
        existingSetups.Add(setup);
    }
    setup.EndDate = currentRoom.Day.Date;
    return existingSetups;
}
```